# R: fastest way to convert matrix to colour raster using given colour lookup table

Tags: r, graphics, colors, rcpp, raster

I am on the lookout for the fastest way in R (or Rcpp) to convert a given matrix of doubles (with values bounded between 0 and 1) to an image raster with hex colour codes.

Currently what I am doing is

```
library(RColorBrewer)
cols=colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, "RdYlBu"))(1080)
colfun=colorRamp(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, "RdYlBu"))
mat=matrix(seq(1:1080)/1080,ncol=1920,nrow=1080,byrow=FALSE)
system.time(rastmat <- as.raster(apply(mat, 2, function (col) rgb(colfun(col),max=255)))) # 2.55s
```

but this is too slow for my application (I would like to be able to do this in under say 0.1s). Would anybody know how to do this efficiently? Either using the colour function `colfun` or using `cols` as a (hash?) lookup table or something like that (after binning the data matrix to the length of `cols`) (whichever is faster)...

Later on the raster would then be displayed using

```
library(grid)
system.time(grid.raster(rastmat,interpolate=FALSE)) # 0.2s
```

Comment: You could look to parallelize your `apply` function using `foreach()` or `mclapply()` instead. It really depends on the operating system and number of cores available

Comment: What is your R version and your CPU? Your code run in 0.6 sec on my computer (R 3.4, Intel core i7, Linux)

Comment: Ha Intel core i7 and R 3.4.0 but Win 8.1. So mclapply() will not be an option - Rcpp and multithreading with OpenMP I guess would be most efficient, thought the solution below is already reasonably performant....

Answer (score 1):

Using a discretization of your color palette and pre-computing the colors I can achieve the task 10 times faster. Considering your code run in 0.5 second on my computer (instead of 2.55 sec in your comment) I perform your task in ~0.05 sec

```
ncol = 100
colfun = colorRamp(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, "RdYlBu"))
col = rgb(colfun(seq(0,1, length.out = ncol)), max = 255)

val2hexa = function(mat, col)
{
  idx = findInterval(mat, seq(0, 1, length.out = length(col)))
  colors = col[idx]
  rastmat = as.raster(matrix(colors, ncol = ncol(mat), nrow = nrow(mat), byrow = FALSE))
  return(rastmat)
}

rastmat <- val2hexa(mat, col)
```

Here the benchmark

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  orig = as.raster(apply(mat, 2, function (col) rgb(colfun(col),max=255))),
  new = val2hexa(mat, col), 
  times = 25)

Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min       lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
 orig 456.36900 466.7336 516.96512 489.52481 560.94217 618.1538    25
  new  49.10714  56.0333  65.29669  57.32988  60.16575 155.7042    25
```

**Edit**

You can gain few millisec like that

```
val2hexa = function(mat, col)
{
  idx = findInterval(mat, seq(0, 1, length.out = length(col)))
  colors = col[idx]
  dim(colors) <- dim(mat)
  rastmat = as.raster(colors)
  return(rastmat)
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for that - with 10 000 colours (which is what I need) I get a timing of 0.07s so that should be good enough! I'll still wait a bit to accept your answer in case someone else might still come up with something faster, e.g. using a hash table, https://blog.dominodatalab.com/a-quick-benchmark-of-hashtable-implementations-in-r/ or some Rcpp+OpenMP solution....

Comment: Using 100 000 colours the timings go down to 0.16s on my machine though....

Comment: `findInterval` use fast internal C code. Then I access the color using the index in a vector. You can't expect to have a faster access to the color with a hash table. And you can't parallelized this task which is already fast. Moreover what is slow in the code is `as.raster(matrix(...)`

Comment: Ha yes I see - so as.raster() would be the one to look at if any faster performance would have to be had... Thx for letting me know!

Comment: Ha just noticed that the as.raster() is not really needed, because given that it's already a matrix of hex colour codes all it would do is a transpose, so we can just do mat=matrix(seq(1:1080)/1080,nrow=1920,ncol=1080,byrow=TRUE) and in your function rastmat = matrix(colors, ncol = nrow(mat), nrow = ncol(mat), byrow = TRUE);class(rastmat)="raster"

Comment: `class(rastmat)="raster"`I tried but the order of the values was not respected and the display was broken

Comment: Ha sorry I meant rastmat = matrix(colors, ncol = nrow(mat), nrow = ncol(mat), byrow = FALSE); class(rastmat)="raster" in your function ie with byrow=FALSE, then it comes out in the right order right? For me it's slightly faster than your 2nd option